# Iterating through cells in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadshet with 149k items in the second column that appear something like this: E1,E2-4,E5,E6,E7-10... Ect. What I want to do is iterate through that column, but on the rows where it has: E2-4 I want it to insert a row above it and break up the numbers. For example: E1, E2-4 Would become: E1,E2,E3,E4. Is there a way I can do this using a macro? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, Zach, it is possible, although it would be fairly complex for a beginner. The expectation on this site is that questions have a limited scope and can be answered in kind. Your question is more of a code-writing request, which isn't appropriate. It would be best for you try writing some code and then ask specific questions as you go. Break your problem in multiple parts and tackle them one at a time.

Comment: So far I have only been able to iterate through and find the ones with hyphon using a test worksheet. The code was with worksheets(1).Range(*B1:B26*) set  C = .Find("-",LookIn:=xlValues)

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to post that code in your question. Format it as a code block. Your next step is figure out how to parse the value into two numbers so you know how many rows to insert. That actually sounds like a question.

Answer (score -2):

Zach let me give you some help, this is by no means a "true answer" more of guide on what you need to research before you ask this question. This is what you want to do

```
Dim Position Long
Dim LastRow long
LastRow = Last Used Row 'many ways to find this
For I = 0 to LastRow
   if instr(Activecell.offset(I,0),"-") >0 then 'would be better as array but this is how most people do things
      position = I -1
      add rows and values
      I= position
   endif
next
```

If you want the more advanced and faster route instead of using the Offset, store all the values in the column in an array variable and do something similar. Like i said this is not an answer, i would try to understand this and do something similar and then ask another question when you hit a wall (if you hit a wall)